# Does TorQ has a general template for creating RTEs?

Tags: kdb, torq

TorQ has templates for creating rdbs, hdbs etc. I cannot seem to find any for rtes. Amy I missing anything or should rtes be created from scratch.

The only thing I see in the codebase that comes close to an rte is :
https://github.com/DataIntellectTech/TorQ-Finance-Starter-Pack/blob/master/code/processes/vwapsub.q